# Magento CE 1.9.1.0 - REST API - Log in as a Customer?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

I've recently had some success on setting up a REST client via PHP to OAuth authenticate on a Magento 1.8.x backend. I've run the same process over on my Magento CE 1.9.1.0.

**Expected authorisation screen:**

[image]

**What actually comes up:**

[image]

Besides the design difference, it does seem that the router takes me to the frontend rather than the backend. I have created a new REST role called Admin with full privileges and have added my main admin user to that role (same process that I used on Magento CE 1.8.x).

Has anyone else experienced this? Could this possibly be a bug?

It seems that no matter what I type into the 'Log In As A Customer' screen, I get redirected to the main customer login page.

My endpoints are as follows:

```
$callbackUrl = "http://foo.bar/test.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://foo.bar/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://foo.bar/oauth/authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://foo.bar/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://foo.bar/api/rest';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seams to work fine for me.
I get the admin authentication screen.
I think you may have used thisthe authorization url `http://magento.root/oauth/authorize` instead of `http://magento.root/admin/oauth_authorize`.

See the examples provided [in here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-Authentication).
There are 2 of them. One for admin access and one for customer access. Use the first one `Create a simple product as an Admin user with OAuth authentication`.

**[EDIT]**
Urls should look like this:

```
$callbackUrl = "http://foo.bar/test.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://foo.bar/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://foo.bar/admin/oauth_authorize'; //this is what you need.
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://foo.bar/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://foo.bar/api/rest';
```

Comment: Thanks Marius. Do you mind posting your endpoints? I have edited my question to include this.

Comment: @FrancisKim Done.